# Python-Evaluating compound if-statements when first value is False

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm experiencing strange behavior in an if-statement with several parts and I simply can't figure out what's going on, though it's clear I'm missing something that at least python thinks is obvious.

Here's the syntax I have:

```
if not(boolean) & (fogXLeft < float(cols[xCol])) < fogXRight) & (fogYBot < float(cols[yCol]) < fogYTop): 
    print "boolean: " + str(boolean)
    boolean = True
```

The issue is that, even when boolean is set to True (and thus not(boolean) is False), the if-statement is entered every time. (I know because "boolean: True" gets printed out over and over.) However, when I comment out the end part, so it's just based on the bool evaluation:

```
if not(boolean): # & (fogXLeft < float(cols[xCol]) < fogXRight) & (fogYBot < float(cols[yCol]) < fogYTop):
    print "boolean: " + str(boolean)
    boolean = True
```

then the if-statement is only entered once (because boolean is set to True from then on).

I thought the issue was conceivably with the compound comparisons (even though I know that's legal syntax), but this also enters the if-statement on every iteration:

```
if not(boolean) & (fogXLeft < float(cols[xCol])): #< fogXRight) & (fogYBot < float(cols[yCol]) < fogYTop):  
    print "boolean: " + str(boolean)
    boolean = True
```

What am I missing here? I am seriously flummoxed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`not` is an operator, not a function. `&` is an operator with higher priority than `not`.

So:

```
if not(boolean) & (fogXLeft < float(cols[xCol])) < fogXRight) & (fogYBot < float(cols[yCol]) < fogYTop):
```

is equivalent to:

```
if not ((boolean) & (fogXLeft < float(cols[xCol])) < fogXRight) & (fogYBot < float(cols[yCol]) < fogYTop)):
```

which in turn, if `boolean` is `True` is equivalent to:

```
if not (1 & (fogXLeft < float(cols[xCol])) < fogXRight) & (fogYBot < float(cols[yCol])  < fogYTop)):
```

which will be true if either of the other two comparison fails.

Answer (score 4):

`&` is a bitwise operator, not `and` operator on conditions. Rather use `and` logical operator, not bitwise operator.

Comment: These two comments together really helped; thanks. I don't exactly understand what & does, though - does it really only evaluate to true if every character of the two things being compared evaluate to 1?